# Is there a way to expose folder outside Spring to be accessed over the Internet?

Tags: java, spring, image, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I am building Spring application that has to expose images over the web.
I tried to store them at Maven's structure's resource directory in static folder,however,whenever an image is uploaded, in order for me to access it over the web I had to restart spring server. I assume this is because spring server is packed as one jar file. My question is, is it possible for me to expose such a folder outside spring so that whenever I upload an image, it would be visible without need to restart spring server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to store the uploaded files outside the project structure and server them statically over Spring (preferably in front of a caching proxy).

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceLocations("file:////path/to/images/on/filesystem/")
    }
```

If the number of images are huge, I would recommend to upload them to an internal / external cloud storage and produce urls that can resolve them. That way you don't have to worry about your images when you scale your app to more than one instance.

Source

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources